# Function with a fixed amount of parameters determined by an integer

Tags: c++, function, c++11, c++14, c++17

I have a class with a template that accepts an integer:

```
template <unsigned int N>
class Example {};
```

I'm looking for a way to define a (member)function that accepts some amount of `Example` objects as arguments. The amount is to be determined by `N`, so the function would be used like this:

```
Function(Example<2>(), Example<2>());
Function(Example<3>(), Example<3>(), Example<3>());
```

**What I tried so far:**

Using an initializer list, one is able to pass a set of objects to the function:

```
template <unsigned int N>
void Function(std::initializer_list<Example<N>> list);
//...
Function({Example<2>(), Example<2>()});
```

However, the problem besides the fact that really only one argument is passed(the list), is that with this method any number of arguments can be used:

```
Function({Example<2>()});
```

I also tried using a variadic function:

```
template <unsigned int N>
void Function(Example<N> e...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, e);
    //...
}
Function(Example<2>(), Example<2>());
```

This makes it possible to use real parameters, but the problem of using any number of arguments remains, and it's not possible to know how many arguments were actually passed.

Comment: of possible interest, complementary to Vittorio Romeo's answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39659127/restrict-variadic-template-arguments

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Assuming you want the number of arguments to be deduced from the `Example<N>` type, and that all `Example<I>` should share the same such `N`, a C++17 solution might be

```
template <unsigned int... I>
auto Function( Example<I>... ) ->
    std::enable_if_t<( ( I == sizeof...(I) ) && ... )>
{
   // or static_assert() if you always want an error
}
```

Comment: Could you please check my answer? I think it can be done in C++11/C++14.

Comment: @Sergey.quixoticaxis.Ivanov sure it can, but a simple, recursively defined type trait would do in that case; the specialization being like *"struct AreSameExamples<N,I,Is...>: std::conditional< I == N, AreSameExamples<N,Is...>, std::false_type >::type {};"*...

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to writing templated (or at least heavily templated) code. Do you mean it's easier to check that all arguments are the same specialization of `S<N>` with a template you described?

Answer (score 5):

Make `Function` a *variadic template* and use `std::enable_if_t` to constrain your it:

- Some `IsExample` trait can be used to make sure that all arguments are instances of `Example`
- `sizeof...(pack)` can be used to get the size of the parameter pack

```
template <unsigned int N, typename... Ts>
auto Function(Ts... xs) 
    -> std::enable_if_t<(IsExample<Ts>::value && ...) 
                     && (sizeof...(Ts) == N)>
{
}
```

[**live example on wandbox**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/n4cEwfPhu87rgzyg)

Comment: if I read the question correctly, the OP wants N to be deduced and doesn't want "Function(Example<0>{}, Example<1>{});" to match ...

Answer (score 4):

You should utilize variadic function template with static_assert. Unlike approaches involving `enable_if` this one will produce a **readable** error message if incorrect arguments are passed.

```
template<unsigned int ... I>
void Function(Example<I>... items)
{
    static_assert
    (
        true && (... && (static_cast<unsigned int>(sizeof...(I)) == I))
    ,   "This function accepts N arguments of type Example<N>"
    );
}
```

[Online compiler](https://wandbox.org/permlink/TZCeaMsrQ8ZZWhra)

Comment: static_assert's explicit error message is helpful indeed.

Comment: You don't need the `true &&` part. `... && x` for an empty pack is `true`.

Comment: @Barry Plus it is at the entirely wrong place if it's meant to handle the empty pack case...

Answer (score 2):

There are many answers that cover SFINAE friendly based constraints, but I don't like placing my SFINAE in the return value:

```
template <unsigned int... Is,
  std::enable_if_t<( ( Is == sizeof...(Is) ) && ... ), bool> = true
>
void Function( Example<Is>... examples )
{
  // code
}
```

or

```
template<bool b>
using test_requirement = std::enable_if_t<b, bool>;

template <unsigned int... Is,
  test_requirement<( ( Is == sizeof...(Is) ) && ... )> = true
>
void Function( Example<Is>... examples )
{
  // code
}
```

Comment: I've spent a more than an hour understanding this =) It's quite hard when your compiler does not support the feature you're trying to dive into.

Comment: @Sergey.quixoticaxis.Ivanov On some compilers, `class = test_requirement< blah >` works but the above does not; however, the above has better overload resolution properties, so I prefer it.

Comment: Ty for the info. Unfortunately msvc in VS2017 seems to consider fold `...` as a syntax error.

Comment: @sergey you will want a C++17 compiler, and MSVC 2017 doesn't even compile all of C++11 yet.

Comment: That's true but there are not too many options on Windows. I've tried Intel and it is (at least on Windows) even worse in my experience.

Answer (score 0):

+1 for the Massimiliano Janes's elegant solution.

Unfortunately use folding so works only for C++17.

To test, with C++11/C++14, that all `I` are equals to `sizeof...(I)` (and maybe that `sizeof...(I)` is equal to `N`, where `N` is the class template argument), it's enough test that a variadic type, that receive unsigned values, is the same type with a different order of values.

I mean: declaring a trivial struct as

```
template <std::size_t ... Is>
struct IList;
```

the test can be

```
std::is_same<IList<N, sizeof...(Is), Is...>,
             IList<sizeof...(Is), Is..., N>>::value
```

Starting from C++14 it's possible to use `std::index_sequence` instead of `IList`.

So `Example` can be written as

```
template <unsigned int N>
struct Example
 {
   template <unsigned int ... Is>
   auto Function (Example<Is> ...)
      -> typename std::enable_if<
            std::is_same<IList<N, sizeof...(Is), Is...>,
                         IList<sizeof...(Is), Is..., N>>::value>::type
    { /* do something */ }
 };
```

The following is a example of use (but remember to include `<type_traits>`)

```
int main()
 {
   Example<1U> e1;
   Example<2U> e2;

   // e1.Function(); // error
   e1.Function(Example<1>{}); // compile
   //e1.Function(Example<1>{}, Example<1>{}); // error

   // e2.Function(); // error
   //e2.Function(Example<2>{}); // error
   e2.Function(Example<2>{}, Example<2>{}); // compile
   //e2.Function(Example<2>{}, Example<2>{}, Example<2>{}); // error
 }
```