# C++17 make_tuple from an argument pack

Tags: c++, tuples, metaprogramming, c++17, template-meta-programming

I would like to do the following but didn't know why it didn't compile in C++17.

```c
int func(int a) {
  // do some operations on a
  int res = operation_on_a(a);
  return res;
}

auto funcs(int... as) {
  return make_tuple(func(as)...);
}

auto v1 = func(1);
auto [v1, v2, v3] = funcs(1, 2, 3);  // Why this doesn't compile?
```

Basically, the idea is to have a base function called `func()` and another function taking variadic arguments applying each item to the `func()` and return a `std::tuple` of the results. However, it doesn't get compiled unless I replaced `int...` with a template type. In this case I know arguments are all integers.

Comment: You *have* to use type parameter pack. You can later `static_assert` to make sure each argument can be converted to an integer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39659127/restrict-variadic-template-arguments/39659128#39659128

Comment: Examples here: https://godbolt.org/g/7kEWzy

Answer (score 2):

> I would like to do the following but didn't know why it didn't compile in C++17.

Simply because

```
auto funcs(int... as) {
  return make_tuple(func(as)...);
}
```

isn't C++ syntax.

I think that

```
template <typename Args>
auto funcs (Args ... as)
 { return std::make_tuple(func(as)...); }
```

taking in count that every `as...` call `func()` that return an `int`, is a reasonable solution.

But if you really want somethig that is like a variadic function that accept a variadic number of `int` (and if you can set an upper limit for the number of arguments), I propose the following solution.

First of all, you need a template that receive a type and a `std::size_t` and return the type; something like

```
template <typename T, std::size_t>
using typer = T;
```

Now an helper recursive `struct` with self-inheritance

```
template <typename>
struct bar;

template <>
struct bar<std::index_sequence<>>
 { 
   static void f () {}
 };

template <std::size_t ... Is>
struct bar<std::index_sequence<Is...>>
   : public bar<std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Is)-1U>>
 {
   using bar<std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Is)-1U>>::f;

   static auto f (typer<int, Is>... as)
    { return std::make_tuple(func(as)...); }
 };
```

that define a sequence of `bar` `struct`s with a `static` method `f` that receive some `int` (`typer<int, Is>` is `int`).

Now a `struct foo`

```
template <std::size_t N = 64U>
struct foo : public bar<std::make_index_sequence<N>>
 { };
```

that inherit from a sequence of `bar` `struct`s and inherit a sequence of `f()` that receive zero, 1, 2, ..., N-1 `int`s.

Now you can call

```
auto [v1, v2, v3] = foo<>::f(1, 2, 3);
```

because in `foo` `struct` there is (also) a `f()` method that receive exactly three `int`s.

The following is a full working example

```
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

int func(int a)
 { return a+1; }

template <typename T, std::size_t>
using typer = T;

template <typename>
struct bar;

template <>
struct bar<std::index_sequence<>>
 { 
   static void f () {}
 };

template <std::size_t ... Is>
struct bar<std::index_sequence<Is...>>
   : public bar<std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Is)-1U>>
 {
   using bar<std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Is)-1U>>::f;

   static auto f (typer<int, Is>... as)
    { return std::make_tuple(func(as)...); }
 };

template <std::size_t N = 64U>
struct foo : public bar<std::make_index_sequence<N>>
 { };

int main ()
 {    
   auto [v1, v2, v3] = foo<>::f(1, 2, 3);

   std::cout << v1 << ", " << v2 << ", " << v3 << std::endl;
 }
```