# Initializing array through explicit constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, aggregate-initialization, explicit-constructor

I'm writing a class that has an explicit constructor taking a `const char*` argument. For the intents and purposes of this question it looks like this:

```
struct Symbol
{
    Symbol()=default;
    explicit Symbol(const char*);
};
```

Now I want to write an example for documentation purposes that initializes an array (array/vector/list - I don't care about the exact type) and I need the example to be as clear and concise as possible. Ideally it would look like this:

```
Symbol symbols[] = { "a", "b", "c"};
```

That does not compile because of the explicit keyword and I am not prepared to make the constructor implicit.

How can I make this work, with the focus of making the example code as expressive as possible?

EDIT:
I went for Bolov's solution with a little help from Caleth:

```
struct Symbol
{
    Symbol();
    explicit Symbol(const char*);

    template <class... Args> 
    static std::array<Symbol, sizeof...(Args)> Array(Args... args)
    {
        return {Symbol{args}...}; 
    } 
};

int main()
{
    auto symbols = Symbol::Array("a", "b", "c");
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, your constructor is explicit so you need to use it as such:

```
Symbol symbols[] = {Symbol{"a"}, Symbol{"b"}, Symbol{"c"}};
```

Both gcc and clang both the copy/move constructor and since C++17 that is the required behavior so there is no performance overhead.

---

If you really want to keep the constructor `explicit` and be able to create an array without explicitly stating it for every element then you can create a helper function:

```
template <class... Args,
          class Enable = std::enable_if_t<(... && std::is_same_v<Args, const char*>)>>
auto make_symbols(Args... args) -> std::array<Symbol, sizeof...(Args)>
{
    return {Symbol{args}...};
}
```

and use it like this:

```
auto symbols = make_symbols("a", "b", "c");
```

Again the move/copies are entirely elided.

The `make_symbols` function uses C++17 features for checking the arguments types. If you need the constraint for a previous standard version (including C++11) see this answer [Restrict variadic template arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39659128/2805305). Or, depending on your needs, removing the check can also be a choice.

Comment: I knew I should have mentioned the obvious solution... That doesn't scale very well.

Comment: what do you mean by "it doesn't scale very well"?

Comment: For every variable, you have to repeat the class name. This makes it less concise than I'd like it to be.

Comment: @bgp2000 Do the constructor *have* to be `explicit`?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude 'fraid so.

Comment: @bolov Can you post make_symbols() as a separate answer? That looks promising.

Comment: Why do you need it as a separate answer? I don't see any benefit for splitting the answer...

Comment: Ok, thanks for the link to your other great post!  This is what I need, but I cannot use C++17 and I can't seem to adapt the C++11 version to my use case of an explicit constructor taking a const char*. See https://godbolt.org/g/4s3ac6.

Comment: I'm not convinced that you need the argument checking here. Anything passing non-symbols fails to instantiate the template. `template <class... Args> std::array<Symbol, sizeof...(Args)> make_symbols(Args... args) { return {Symbol{args}...}; }`

Comment: @Caleth maybe he has other constructors he doesn't want to kick in here. I don't know. It's an option if he wants.

Comment: @bgp2000 have you tried? because in the link I see only code from the original post, no attempt to modify it to your needs. Anyway here it is: https://godbolt.org/g/BCc7E8

Comment: I did try it. Thanks for the working code! I think @Caleth's version is what I need. It doesn't clutter up my header as much and catches errors like `make_symbols(false)`.

Answer (score 1):

The best I've come up with so far is:

```
std::vector<Symbol> symbols;
for(auto v: { "a", "b", "c"})
    symbols.emplace_back(v);
```