# Variable number of arguments for template in C++ with a certain type

Tags: c++, c++17

[Variable number of arguments in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1657883/variable-number-of-arguments-in-c)
In this post you will find a way to write variable arguments for template,

```
template <typename T>
void func(T t) 
{
    std::cout << t << std::endl ;
}

template<typename T, typename... Args>
void func(T t, Args... args) // recursive variadic function
{
    std::cout << t <<std::endl ;

    func(args...) ;
}
```

But in my case, type name is certain,

```
template <int... args>
constexpr auto sum(int a, ...) {
    return a + sum(args...);
}
constexpr auto sum(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}
void test() {
    cout << sum(1, 2) << endl;
    cout << sum(1, 2, 3) << endl;
    cout << sum(1, 2, 3, 4) << endl;
}
```

It's not working with `sum(args...)`, prompts error

```
Error   C2660   '__syntaxTest::sum': function does not take 0 arguments ForTest
```

Do you have any suggestion about this?

Comment: There's no way the compiler could deduce `<int ... args>` from `sum(1, 2)` (or other invocations). Moreover `sum(int a, ...)` does not to what you think it does

Comment: See dupe: [Can I create a function which takes any number of arguments of the same type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70014236/can-i-create-a-function-which-takes-any-number-of-arguments-of-the-same-type)

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/c5q39qvea here is an example that shows what is wrong with your code. `(int a, ...)` is a *C variadic*, not a template variadic. The link shows you the difference.